# php array key issue

Tags: php, arrays

ok so i have the following array:

**0 - 208533**

1 - 208523

2 - 208522

3 - 208572

4 - 208518

5 - 208501

6 - 208534

7 - 208499

All i need is a quick function that'll start the array key at 1 rather than 0.

eg: **1 - 208533** etc

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well one quick way to do it is:

```
array_unshift($array, null); // inject a dummy value at beginning
unset($array[0]); // unset the dummy value, the rest of the keys are preserved
```